# How do I step through/debug a python web application?

Tags: python, debugging, step-into

I can't seem to find any information on debugging a python web application, specifically stepping through the execution of a web request.

is this just not possible? if no, why not?

Comment: How are you running the web application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you put

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

in your code, the web app will drop to a pdb debugger session upon executing `set_trace`.

Also useful, is

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

which drops you to the python interpreter. Pressing Ctrl-d resumes execution.

Still more useful, is

```
import IPython.Shell 
ipshell = IPython.Shell.IPShellEmbed()
ipshell(local_ns=locals())
```

which drops you into an IPython session (assuming you've installed IPython). Here too, pressing Ctrl-d resumes execution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your web application through apache and [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Python_Interactive_Debugger) or [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/python10/), both provide some support for step through debugging with pdb.  The trick is you have to run apache in foreground mode with the -X flag.

On my Gentoo system I do this with (this is essentially the same command the apache init script uses replacing the -k start with the -X):

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D LANGUAGE -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D PYTHON -d /usr/lib64/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -X
```

Comment: You might also need to enable PythonEnablePdb option as documented in the modpython docs here - http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/directives.html#pythonenablepdb

Answer (score 0):

use Python Debbuger, `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` exactly where you want to start debugging, and your terminal will pause in that line.
More info here:
http://plone.org/documentation/kb/using-pdb